# Construction of inverse point in sphere

Tags: transformation, geometric-construction, mobius-inversion

i would like to know if my construction of inverse point of A in sphere, A' is right. First of all i constructed a line through pole $S$ and $A$, then i drew a line through $N$ perpendicular to $AS$. Their point of intersection i named $I$. Then, intersection of $NI$ and $OA$ is an image of $A$, $A'$. 
[image]

Comment: All of these points are coplanar, so when restricted to this plane, does this construction reduce to the construction of inversion in a circle?

Comment: yes, it reduces to the construction of inversion in a circle  @amd

Comment: Are you sure about that? Try working this construction out analytically in the plane. The point $A'$ that results is not the inversion of $A$, as can be seen by examining the product of their distances from $O$.